# vuejs for loop always return the last value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vuejs2

In vuecli I have data like this

```js
data() {
        return {
            options: [{
                values: ['a', 'b', 'c']
            }],
            variants: [],
            p: {            
               option_1: null 
            }
        }
    }
```

and when i run a loop inside a method that looks like this

```js
methods: {
  add() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.options[0].values.length; i++) {

        (function(i, p){
            var raw = p;
            raw.option_1 = this.options[0].values[i]; 
            this.variants.push(raw); 
        })(i, this.p);

    } 
  }
}
```

I tried in many ways but succeed only when I set the value of `raw` inside the loop like`var raw = {option_1: null}` .

But this is not what i want. I want to take values from `data` and use it in the loop to produce

```
variants: [{ option_1: 'a' }, { option_1: 'b' }, { option_1: 'c' }]
```

How can I accomplish this ??

Comment: What is `self` in that function? Also, what is the point of this loop function? You overwrite `p.option_1` each iteration. Can you explain what you want the end state to be?

Comment: sorry self will be 'this'. I fixed it. I want to push 'option' values into variants array. But I am getting the value 'c' three times instead of 'a' 'b' 'c'

Comment: variants: [{
  option_1: 'a'
}, {
  option_1: 'b'
}, {
  option_1: 'c'
}]
but I am getting 'c' for three times

Comment: What about if `add()` is called multiple times?

Comment: I think its something related to 'closure' but i cant figure out the solution

Comment: Before for, have something like var self = this; And instead of using this inside self calling functions, use self.

Comment: Yes, your problem is somewhat related to this ~ [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/283366). You also have an issue in that you are pushing the same object into your array and changing its property, thus they all have the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a copy of `raw` because `raw` in `variants` is just a reference which point to the same object. That's why you got three same value.

```
add() {
  let self = this
  for (let i = 0; i < self.options[0].values.length; i++) {
    (function (i, p) {
      var raw = p;
      raw.option_1 = self.options[0].values[i];
      self.variants.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(raw)));
    })(i, self.p);
  }
  // this.options[0].values.forEach(v => {
  //     this.variants.push({ option_1: v })
  // })
}
```

Code in the comment is a more elegant way.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <mytag></mytag>
</div>
<script>
  let mytag = Vue.component("mytag", {
    template: `<div><button @click="add">add</button><p>this.variants:{{this.variants}}</p></div>`,
    data() {
      return {
        options: [{
          values: ["a", "b", "c"]
        }],
        variants: [],
        p: {
          option_1: null
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
      add() {
        let self = this
        for (let i = 0; i < self.options[0].values.length; i++) {
          (function(i, p) {
            var raw = p;
            raw.option_1 = self.options[0].values[i];
            self.variants.push(Object.assign({}, raw));
            //self.variants.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(raw)));
          })(i, self.p);
        }
        // this.options[0].values.forEach(v => {
        //     this.variants.push({ option_1: v })
        // })
      }
    }
  });
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      mytag
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This seems very over-complicated. There's really no need for the IIFE nor for the JSON parse / stringify. A for loop with `this.variants.push({option_1: this.options[o].values[i]})` is all you need

Comment: There is a more elegant way in the comments. And which part in the comments  you think is over-complicated ?@Phil

Comment: Yes, your `forEach` is much cleaner though it omits any extra properties that `p` might have

Comment: @Phil,yeah,it depends whether OP needs `p` or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the end result to look like

```js
variants: [{
  option_1: 'a'
}, {
  option_1: 'b'
}, {
  option_1: 'c'
}]
```

Where each entry is templated by `p` with `option_1` set to each `values` entry, you can use

```js
this.variants = this.options[0].values.map(option_1 => ({...this.p, option_1 }))
```

This maps the *values* to an array of objects with key `option_1` and the value from each *values* item.

---

If you want to add the 3 objects each time you call `add()`, change it to use `Array.prototype.concat()`

```js
this.variants = this.variants.concat(
    this.options[0].values.map(option_1 => ({...this.p, option_1 })))
```